# Using for-loop values to create a basic graph

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I have wrapped a C library in python using ctypes and called the DLLs. I then created a for-loop that prints out all of my data. Here is a small sample of the code that I have wrapped.

```
import ctypes 
from ctypes import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ParmData(Union):
_fields_ = [
     ('c', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)),
     ('f', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))]
class SParm(Structure):
pass
 SParm._fields_ = [
    ('data', ctypes.POINTER(ParmData)),
    ('time', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))]

dll.readSParm.argtypes = (POINTER(SFile), c_char_p, c_double, c_double,    c_double, POINTER(TTag), c_ushort,)   
dll.readSParm.restype = POINTER(SParm)
g = dll.readSParm(SF, ParmName, startTime, stopTime, Null, None, convertType)
dll.freeSParm(g)
```

I want to create a simple graph with data points that are printed out from a for loop. This is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(0, 1032):
x = (g[0].time[i])
y = (g[0].data[0].f[i])
print(i, x, y)
```

This for-loop works perfectly and prints out all of the data into a neat list, but I need that list to be plotted into a simple graph. The return of the for-loop looks like this:

```
1028 -1.2241029739379883 1.7323481895261962e+19
1029 -0.22411400079727173 2.635080461412465e+23
1030 0.7759910225868225 1.7829588197038883e+19
1031 1.7759920358657837 1.8027558490491145e+28
```

Where the second column corresponds to the time value and the third column is the data values for that time.

I set x and y equal to pointers to objects that are contain all of the data.
I'm having a difficult time getting that data into a graph. idk what i'm doing wrong because in most of the matplotlib examples they just create random data and plot it. I need a way to get my data into the graph.
This doesn't work:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

It builds a graph, but it doesn't populate the data into the graph. This is what my graph looks like which is no good.
[image: Bad Graph]

## My question is this:

how can I get my data from a printed list of value pairs into a basic graph?

Comment: Have you tried giving the line a color? plt.plot(x,y,'-r')

Comment: Your x and y get reinitialised in the for loop, I guess you might want to build a list instead.

Comment: I guess that using `plot(g[0].time, g[0].data[0].f)` should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x and y are single floats, not arrays as indicated by the output of your print statement. `plt.plot()` tries to draw lines between points, but since there is only one point, there can be no line. I would assume you want to somehow make x and y into arrays of values perhaps something like this...

```
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0, 1032):
    x.append(g[0].time[i])
    y.append(g[0].data[0].f[i])
```

then when passed to `plt.plot` there is more than one point to plot
alternately if you want a scatter plot on non-connected points, use `plt.scatter`

Comment: Why populate a new list when the data is already in `g[0].time` and  `g[0].data[0].f`?

Comment: @Bart I thought about that, but was unsure if this object's fields supported the full `__slice__` notation given that it was from a custom wrapped library. I'm not too sure how that whole process shakes down.